# Problem " driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='example']"

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I have been experiencing this problem for a few days. I use Pycharm and Python:

```py
UserWarning: find_element_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_element() instead
warnings.warn("find_element_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_element() instead")
```

Regards

Comment: OK, so what's the problem? They're just warnings.

Comment: hi... Warnings for what?

Comment: @lolino it's a warning for the `Deprecated` method also given the suggestion for the available method which you could use

Answer (score 1):

Try the following...

First, import By as follows: `from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By`

Then if you're trying to find an element by xpath, for example, replace:

`find_elements_by_xpath("[***whatever the xpath is***]")`

with:

`driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "[***whatever the xpath is***]")`

For examples of the various ways to call elements refer to [this reference website for Selenium with Python](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)